# Dotnet not installed in ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, error occurs

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu

When downloading via terminal bash ./dotnet-install.sh --version latest, an error occurs

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
dotnet_install: Error: Extraction failed

gzip and tar updated.

Comment: I was under the impression Ubuntu has dotnet sdk in the standard packages? So do you have a specific reason to install via shell script?

Comment: There seems to be a Microsoft-Feed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-microsoft-package-repository which would be slightly more on the cutting edge as the feed from canonical https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu-2204